# the markup in the document following the root must be well formed

Tags: android, eclipse, domdocument, markup

I am getting the error "the markup in the document following the root must be well formed" in my XML. I am not sure what is causing this, here's my code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/TopTwoButtons"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/background_meduim"
android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ListButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="39dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
    android:src="@drawable/list_button_medium" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/SearchButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ListButton"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/search_button_medium" />
</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/BottomTwoButtons"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/TopTwoButtons"
android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/InfoButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:src="@drawable/info_button_medium" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/PopularButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:src="@drawable/popular_button_medium" >



</RelativeLayout>
```

Update code, still getting the error "the markup in the document following the root must be well formed"

Answer (score 0):

There should be one root element for any layout file. The two relative layouts would be the child elements for the root.

Your code should look like

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/TopTwoButtons" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/background_meduim" android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/ListButton"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_marginRight="39dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
     android:src="@drawable/list_button_medium" />

    <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/SearchButton"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ListButton"
     android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
     android:src="@drawable/search_button_medium" />
     </RelativeLayout>
     <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/BottomTwoButtons"    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/TopTwoButtons" android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

     <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/InfoButton"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_centerInParent="true"
     android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
     android:src="@drawable/info_button_medium" />

     <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/PopularButton"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_centerInParent="true"
     android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
     android:src="@drawable/popular_button_medium" >
     </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```